# How to see if a post exists based on a meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to see if a post exists by a meta value?

For instance, lets say I want to see if another post has a unique meta value of "pictureID", and if so do something else.

Is there a way I could write that clause in php?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you dont know the post id then

you can use custom wordpress query to check post meta according to key like

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( "select * from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = 'pictureID' " );
```

And then you can get all results with post id and then get that post data.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a standard [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to return posts by `meta_key` using the `meta_query` argument and `EXISTS` compare type.

```
// query for all posts with the pictureID meta key set
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', // or your_custom_post_type
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'pictureID',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
}

// create a custom query
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// loop over your query, creating a custom The Loop
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ): while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post();
    // $post is now posts that have a pictureId meta value
endwhile; endif;

// reset $post
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you want to quickly grab a random post_id that has this meta_key set you can go to the database directly (bypassing caching, etc).

```
global $wpdb;

// SQL statement to fetch the post_id using a meta_key and a published post
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm 
    JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p 
      ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
        AND post_status = 'publish' 
        AND post_type = 'post'
    WHERE meta_key = 'pictureID' 
      AND meta_value != ''
      AND post_id != %d
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 1
SQL;

// exclude the current post by replacing %d with the current ID
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post->ID );

// use get_var() to return the post_id
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to get meta  value for post [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
$postMetaValue=get_post_meta($postId,"meta_key",true);
if($postMetaValue=='pictureID')
  {
     //do as you want
  }
```

Comment: It's said check meta exist based on meta key, get_post_meta() need $post_id